# Magento - No items showing on Order View page in admin backend

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

For some reason, items ordered are no longer being rendered on the Order View page in the backend.

[image]

But they are rendered on the Shipping details page:

[image]

I have cleared the cache fully.

Viewing the source, there is nothing rendered underneath the grey heading bar "Items Ordered".

Any ideas folks?

Comment: Did you check your php error logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload the folder /app/design/adminhtml/ again. For me its work!